# How to get DPI from a PSD file

Tags: c#, .net, photoshop

I have few PSD files 
I am converting the file to jpg using http://imageresizing.net/ library

How to get DPI information from a PSD file using C#?

**Update**
I have wrote following code however issue with this is
it opens photoshop in background

```
ps.Application a = new ps.Application() { Visible = false };
a.Load(filePath);
ps.Document doc = a.ActiveDocument;
dpi = doc.Resolution;
a.ActiveDocument.Close();
a.Quit();
```

Comment: Isn't dpi a printer attribute? Perhaps you're thinking of 'resolution'?

Comment: @Strawberry no, theres a density property of a photoshop file.

Comment: Daniel, user1941944 - you've both lost me :-$  Surely the 'resolution' of a photoshop file is expressed in pixels (ppi), not dots?

Answer (score 1):

These are the first settings that I use when I open PS programatically:

```
                // Open PhotoShop
                app = new ps.Application();
                app.Preferences.RulerUnits = ps.PsUnits.psPixels;
                app.DisplayDialogs = ps.PsDialogModes.psDisplayNoDialogs;
                app.Visible = false;
```